# Can't get big enough partition Windows 10 disk for installing Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows-10

I have a Windows 10 system with a 500 GB disk.  I can't create a partition of greater that 7 GB to install Ubuntu.  I have deleted a lot of Windows 10 files and have defragmented with both MS's defrag and Piriform Defragger with little luck.

I have 325 GB of free space on C:. I want to install a dual boot system.  Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried resizing the Windows partition *from within Windows* to make it smaller?

Comment: this was required with older Windows, not sure if still same. Resize Vista partition, similar for 7
If problems, try disabling system restore, pagefile, (in advanced settings in computer properties) and hibernate option (in power management). Don’t forget to turn them on back later.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you dual booting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting files increases the free size in a partition, but it does not resize the partition. You can resize the partitions in Windows with the disk manager (enter 'Create and format hard disk partitions' into the Windows search field). You could also use a tool like gparted from a live system on DVD or USB.

But pay attention at what you are doing!

Answer (score 1):

You need to shrink your Windows 10 partition. Any number from 30 to 60 GB should be more than enough for Ubuntu. From [these instructions](http://dailylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-shrink-windows-10-to-make-space.html) you can see the Windows 10 screen:

[image: Windows 10 shrink partition]

Comment: I am using Diskmgmt, as suggested, but the utility says under "Size of available shrink space in MB" 7744.  Way too small.  How can I increase it?

Comment: Defragmentation is not necessary. The resize function does that automatically. You have to select C: with a right-click in disk manager, there you can resize the partition.